# How to make parent method throw exception?

Tags: java, exception, runnable

How do I get the anonymous `runnable` to make the parent method throw an exception?

```
public boolean drive2Exit() throws Exception {
    while(true) {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ...
                catch (Exception e) {
                    //drive2Exit should throw exception
                }
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be valuable to tag your question with the language you're using. Some people may be able to determine it anyway, but many cannot.

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is not possible for a few reasons. Why do you want this kind of functionality? You do understand the flow of execution thats going on here, yeah?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @VinceEmigh Sorry if this doesn't make sense. I basically want to add a simple postDelay() in my original method. postDelay() basically tells the method to run at a later time with a pause between each iteration in the while loop. However, my original method threw an exception and I don't know how to handle that.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. If an exception is thrown in `run()`, and you want to handle the exception in `driveToExit()`, then you cannot use `Runnable`, since it can't throw exceptions. You could use `Future`, but you cannot handle the exception until you call `Future#get()`, and `postDelay` probably doesn't return a future instance. **What is the type of `postDelay`, and where is it from? Could you replace `postDelay(Runnable)` with an `ExecutorService#schedule(Callable<T>)`?**

Comment: @VinceEmigh postDelay() is a method that belongs to Handler, which is part of Android. I'll research ExecutorService, if it can pause the iteration for a few milliseconds each time then that could probably work.

Comment: Do you use `Handler`s messaging system?

Comment: If you're still having troubles, you can always start a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) for this question. I wanted to know if you used Handler's messaging system because if not, then replacing it with `ExecutorService` is a piece of cake. If you do, then you need to create your own queue to store the messages

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yep, I am using the Handler's messaging system. However, I have managed to compensate the problem by handling the exception with try catch. I am definitely interested in what would be the best course of action in a case such as this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would probably be best server with the use of a Future:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

using that you can in your main code check the result of the runnable and if it threw an exception you will get exception to process in the code checking the future. use that exception and i think the embedded original exception to decide what to throw outside the Future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if you can do that. When exception get raised in child thread and it's not catched, child thread would simply die without parent knowing about it. What I can think of is that `catch` the `Exception` in child and put it in a shared data structure e.g. a `static` variable shared among children and parent. Parent would periodically poll this data structure if there is any exception in it's child.
Or you can implement `Observer` design pattern to notify `main` thread when there is new exception in any of the child (i.e. shared data structure is changed.)